# What's the best way to stop celery app if worker initializing failed

Tags: python, celery

I have some logic in worker_process_init signal:

```
@worker_process_init.connect
def init_per_worker_publisher(**kwargs):
    # some init logic...
```

If there appears unhandled exception, setup function is failed and no init happens but worker app keeps running like nothing happened.

I solved this problem like this:

```
@worker_process_init.connect
def init_per_worker_publisher(**kwargs):
    try:
        # some init logic...
    except Exception:
        celery_app.control.shutdown()
```

Maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can raise a `WorkerShutdown` exception.

```
from celery.exceptions import WorkerShutdown

@worker_process_init.connect
def init_per_worker_publisher(**kwargs):
    try:
        # some init logic...
    except Exception:
        raise WorkerShutdown()
```